# LibreOffice Calc Basic: getCellByPosition gives outOfBoundsException

Tags: scripting, libreoffice, basic, calc

I have the following macro in a Calc file:

```
Dim oDoc as Object
oDoc=ThisComponent
Dim oSheets as Object
oSheets = oDoc.Sheets
Dim oController as Object
oController = oDoc.getCurrentController()
Dim numVisibleSheet
numVisibleSheet = oController.VisibleRange.Sheet
Dim currentSheet as Object
currentSheet = oController.ActiveSheet
currentSheet = oSheets.getByIndex(numVisibleSheet)

MsgBox "ok"
cell = currentSheet.getCellByPosition(5000, 5)
cell.setString("toto")
```

When I run it on LibreOffice 7, I get an 'outOfBoundsException' in cellsuno.cxx.

Is my use of getCellByPosition bad? Are there bounds on the x and y coordinates for a cell, and if so how can I expand these bounds?

Thanks!

Comment: Basic absolutely rightly scolds you for this line. The Calc worksheet has a total of 1024 columns, but you require a sixth row cell and 5001th columns. If you meant cell F5001 then write `currentSheet.getCellByPosition(5, 5000)`

Comment: Doh... I mixed lines and columns??? I'll try that, thanks! EDIT: yep that's it... I feel dumb! Thanks again!

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer.

Comment: @Yunnosch I don't think that this question and the answer to it can be of any use to anyone - this is a common technical error, a typo in the code. It would be better if the author just deletes the question along with our comments.

Comment: @JohnSUN Useful or not is handled via votes. Off-topic or not via close-votes. Really hamrfully bad via delete-votes or flags. But solved or not is not handled by content at all, only by answer present or not, maybe be accept-ticking. "I don't care anymore." is best represented by deleting, I agree.